# Google Script - trigger working but email not sending

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a long standing form/spreadsheet/script - that send emails triggered on spreadsheet edit.  The trigger is working but the email is not sending.  I have dropped the script and recreated - which authorized again.

```
function sendNotification() { 
  //Get Active spreadsheet and worksheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Change Requests");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email Addresses");

  //Set row for which to send notification
  //get values
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = lastRow.getValues();

  //Other Variables
  var body = "<HTML><BODY>";
  var stuNumber = values[0][2];
  var stuName = values[0][3].toString();
  var stuHouse = values[0][5].toString();
  var gradeLevel = values[0][6].toString();
  var oldCourse = values[0][7].toString();
  var newCourse = values[0][8].toString();
  var subject = "New course change request submitted for " + stuName;
  var academicAdviser;
  var cc_recipients = sheet2.getRange(4, 2).getValue();

  //Send notification email
  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail(academicAdviser, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, noReply: "True", cc: cc_recipients})
  }
  catch (f) {
    Browser.msgBox(f.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Put this in your code `Logger.log(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota())` and see what value you are getting Or log the error from catch block here.

Answer (score 1):

**In this line:**

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
```

spreadsheet is set to the activeSheet which is not a spreadsheet

**In this line:**

```
var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

row is undefined.

**In this Line:**

```
MailApp.sendEmail(academicAdviser, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, noReply: "True", cc: cc_recipients})
```

academicAdviser is undefined and  htmlBody is set to `<HTML><BODY>` which will produced no output for htmlBody parameter.

**Instead of Using this:**

```
Browser.msgBox(f.message);
```

You might consider using SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt() or alert()

And I think it's a good idea to add MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() somewhere to keep yourself from running over your quota.

After looking at your code I'd guess that it might be a good idea for you to read [this section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).